# How can we Create a Trigger(or any Object) to insert rows into Attendance table when a certain time of day passes?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I am new to PL/SQL and Oracle APEX. In oracle APEX, I'm trying to create a trigger that will fire when employees are not present after a certain time, say for example 12:00 PM and it's not friday.
I have these columns in the Attendances Table: emp_id, work_date, attend_stat.
The emp_id is a foreign key referenced from Employees Table
When it's past 12:00 PM, and there was no attendance entry for a particular employee, I want a row inserted for that employee like this:

```
insert into attendances(emp_id, work_date, attend_Stat)
values("ID OF NOT PRESENT EMPLOYEE", sysdate, 'A');
```

I have written this pl/sql statement but I cannot find a way to implement it or figure out will it even work.

```
     declare
        cursor c_emp_id is
        select emp_id from employees;
        cursor c_emp_at is
        select emp_id from attendances where work_date = sysdate and to_char(sysdate,'DAY') <> 'FRIDAY';
        begin
        for i in c_emp_id loop
        for a in c_emp_at loop
        if i.emp_id <> a.emp_id then
        insert into attendances(emp_id, work_date, attend_stat)
        values(i.emp_id, systimestamp, 'A');
        end if;
        end loop;
        end loop;
    exception
    when no_data_found then
    for i in c_emp_id loop
    insert into attendances(emp_id, work_date, attend_stat)
    values(i.emp_id, systimestamp, 'A');
end loop;
        end;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you would like to insert a row into the attendance table for the employee who has not logged in even at 12, then sure, you can do it. First, tell me how do you check whether an employee has already logged in before 12. I mean how will you make that entry ? Who will do that ? If you are only planning to insert those employees who have not logged in even at 12, then you can create a job that calls a stored procedure that inserts the rows into this attendance table exactly at 12 if there is no row already for that employee for that day.

Comment: I have a page for attendance entry where selecting a date generates attendance for all employees on that day with their IDs, Departments and jobs. I made the ID as link which calls a modal page for that employee to confirm their attendance for that day with a button, when they click that button, in the attendance table, the exact time is inserted into a timestamp column. I just want a row inserted if there was no changes made on that modal page. I should also mention that this project is my first project using Oracle APEX.

Comment: Seems like you were very busy after posting this question on this forum. You got free to check this out only after almost 5 days. So, expect the answer from anyone here only when they get time. Good luck with that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I only noticed your comment yesterday. I saw one answer below and thought that was the only comment. I'm new to this website. I once again apologize if u think I've in any way ignored your comment. I'm grateful you've tried to solve my issue but totally understandable if you ignore it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the code in a package or in a stored procedure and set it to run as a database job. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12384) for details.
Please note the doc is for version 11 of the database, check the version you are on

```
select version from v$instance
```

and google for actual docs

Comment: I don't have any local database installed. I'm creating the app on the online version of APEX. Is there a way to do it online only? With no local database?

Comment: Sorry, @Adnan I have no experience with APEX. If there is a way to execute a pl/sql code from there, then it might work.